# Read and substitute constants in XML during XSL transformation

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml with the structure,

```
<root>

  <constant name="user">johndoe</constant>
  <constant name="server">1</constant>

  <connection>
    <userName>${user}</userName>
    <port>1234</port>
    <server>matrix.${server}.abc.com</server>
  </connection>

</root>
```

I'm extracting the information using XSLT to a CSV structure. How do I replace the constant names with their actual values? If this can be done in XSL, then I also have a few cases of 'nested' constants like,

```
<constant name="a">123</constant>
<constant name="b">10${a}</constant>
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0?

Comment: @IanRoberts yes, I can use XSLT 2.0

Comment: Then, for your future questions, please tag them as `xslt-2.0` straightaway. This time, I've done it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say in a comment that you can use XSLT 2.0 then it's a relatively straightforward use of `analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:const="urn:const"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="const xs">

  <!-- variable holding the input tree root for use inside analyze-string -->
  <xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

  <xsl:key name="constant" match="constant" use="@name" />

  <!-- declare a function that you can call as const:replace(string) for any
       string in which you want to expand out references to constants -->
  <xsl:function name="const:replace" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="text" as="xs:string?" />
    <xsl:variable name="result" as="xs:string*">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="\$\{{(.*?)\}}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:sequence select="key('constant', regex-group(1), $root)" />
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:sequence select="." />
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- analyze-string gives us a sequence of strings, join them into one
         as the overall result of this function -->
    <xsl:sequence select="string-join($result, '')" />
  </xsl:function>

  <!-- some templates to demonstrate the function in use -->

  <!-- drop constant elements from output -->
  <xsl:template match="constant" />

  <!-- copy other elements and attributes unchanged -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- expand ${constant} references in text nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="const:replace(.)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The magic regular expression is `\$\{(.*?)\}`, but the brace characters have to be doubled because the `regex` attribute of `analyze-string` is treated as an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates).

Handing constants within constants is trivial, by making the function recursive

```
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:sequence select="const:replace(
                  key('constant', regex-group(1), $root))" />
        </xsl:matching-substring>
```

A couple of caveats: this will enter an infinite loop if there are circular definitions (`a=foo${b}`, `b=bar${a}`), and references to undeclared constants will disappear (`foo.${undeclared}.bar` becomes `foo..bar`), though it would be fairly straightforward to adapt the function to either flag these as an error or leave them unchanged.

Comment: Thanks again! unfortunately I encountered this error: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException 'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference.' I believe this might be due to limitations of the processor in JDK7 and I might need to package an external processor with my code, umm what would you suggest?

Comment: @Rnet as I hinted in my latest comment on your previous question, the default XSLT processor behind `javax.xml.transform` in the JDK only supports XSLT 1.0. If you want to use 2.0 you need to use Saxon 9. For basic non-schema-aware processing the open-source "HE" version from [SourceForge](http://saxon.sourceforge.net) is sufficient, if you need more advanced features the commercial editions can be purchased at http://saxonica.com

Comment: ah, sorry I must have missed that. Thanks for your time and help!